# Pinging a dead cellphone

Tags: rf, wireless, cellphone

Can a dead phone still be pinged? I was watching a news clip recently of someone lost in the woods with a dead phone that still managed to be pinged. How it this possible? I'd imagine it's some sort of analog response to a targeted scan by a tower or satellite? My understanding was that this is not possible.

Comment: Im a cs guy, know very little about hardware, though this would be the best place to ask, sorry if its not. im familiar with how cell towers can triangulate a location using ping but the device has to be on and connected to the network I thought.

Answer (score 1):

If the phone is literally without a power source, than it is not connected to the cellular network and cannot communicate.  However, up until the point where the power goes out, the phone is still communicating with the network, and which cellular towers it was near is recorded.  Since people do not walk very quickly, you can still find a dead phone by asking the network where (very approximately) it was last located.  Chances are it will still be there a few hours later.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be possible if the battery is weak, such that simultaneously:

- the phone, somewhere in the higher layers (e.g., the OS, like iOS or android) has shut for low battery reasons
- either (a) the cellular chipset is still powered, because the phone is not completely dead yet. As such, it might be in idle mode, where it has sent a *location update* message to the nearest base station some time ago, and may still be listening for base station beacon signals
- or (b) even the cellular chipset is powered off, and the phone is really dead, BUT it managed to send a location update message to the nearest base station some time ago before the phone went dead.

In either case ((a) or (b)), the network would have some knowledge of where the phone is. That may be all that was needed for this case. The location area would be known from the last location update.

It need not actually be "pinging" the phone (with a *paging* message), as anyway, if the phone is dead, it wouldn't be able to hear that and respond.

By the way, these days, most mobile phones are digital phones (the analog phone systems have shut down in many countries around the world), so the location updates, beacons, etc., would be digital messages (not analog, as suggested in the question).

Answer (score -4):

Cellphone has RSSI (relative signal strength indicator), which is a logarithm output summation of a number of quasi_logarithmic differential_in_out signal compression stages.

For the original FM Motorola phones, with modulation coming from the timing of the zero crossings (that is FM), such chips as the NE605

- 102 dB gain
- over 90 dB RSSI range
- 0.22 microVolts input (to mixer) for +12dB SINAD ino 455 Hz IF output (+-5Khz bandwidth?)

were used in those BRICK sized phones.

And the phone would loyally report its internal RSSI measurement, of the cell tower power, back to the cell tower.

The cell tower needed to know the signal strength at the handset, so the cell tower could plan when to handoff that human to another cell tower, either because the cell tower became really busy with many users, or the human was walking/driving away from that cell tower and the signal was getting too weak for good FM communication.

Comment: How does this answer the question?